# Websocket only vs Websocket with rest for sending messages

Tags: java, spring, rest, websocket, software-design

I learning Spring and I choose chat application as my training application. I want implement all the best as it possible to learn good practices.

Now, I want implement sending and receiving messages. It is possible to do with websocket, but I also want receive response of that sending message to show client if his message was sent or not. (similiar as messenger)

Is possible to do that with pure websocket in spring or should I use websocket for whole communication (sending and receiveing)?

Also I want later implement other stuff like sending files, getting some data like chat history and so on. And there is same question as above. Should I use one websocket connection for that or use websocket channel just for one purpose, e.g chatting, and other stufs where is no required realtime communication do with rest? What are pros and cons? Thanks in answer for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have your recipuent send back a receipt object saying it received a message with message ID. If this doesn't come back in a certain time then mark it not received.

Comment: For this solution to work, client has to send some kind of ID or reference which server has to persist. This way when server sends back the ack, the client would be able to identify the actual message. Another way to achieve this would be to use rest api call (only for sending new message), but, this will not be realtime and is not a better approach.